# How can I install previous versions of any module in python (vs code)?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I was installing scikit learn and tensorflow but I was having an error:-
"Could not find a version that satisfies your requirements."

I want to do machine learning and therefore I need these modules .

Pls help me out.

Comment: Have you tried indicate the version number using '=='?
```pip install somthing=1.2.5'
```

Answer (score 2):

To resolve this issue, use  `pip install sckit-learn==<your-version>` and `pip install tensorflow==<your-version>` or use `pip install sckit-learn` and `pip install tensorflow` to install their latest versions. Replace  with a version like. If it the installation fails that version of the package does not exist.